# Send every request to a page other than index.php to 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been looking into securing my php site, and I would like to know how I can hide the structure of my site in a believable fashion, that is, send every file or directory but the index file to a not found page with a 404 header, so I can block access to files like .htaccess or my library files without letting the user know that they even exist...
Thank you for reading and have a nice day!

Comment: Use robot.txt , see documentation  : http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: You can use your `.htaccess` to block access to the folders you want with `Deny from all`. If your `.htaccess` is viewable it means that Apache is not properly configured, by default it should be impossible to access it.

Comment: @Fky it only blocks indexing robots, not humans or scrapers.

Comment: Use .htaccess as A.L. suggested or alternatively put index.php into a /public folder and then point your virtual host to that as the document root.

Comment: @A.L that sends the user to a unauthorized page, and is not what I am looking for. I want to send the user to a not found page with a 404 html header emitted, to make it as believable that the page he is trying to access (and that might exist) does not exist, so that I'm safe from users trying to find the structure of my site

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, it will send a 404. If the file exists, then it will be served. If you don't want it served, don't put it in a place that Apache can see. As mentioned, if you can see `.htaccess` you've broken something badly as it's hidden out of the box. If this is not helpful, you need to clarify your question more. This may be more appropriate for serverfault.com

Comment: I want it to send a 404 even if it exists, if it's not named index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read some of my old code and found a solution, I don't if it's elegant but it works very nicely...

```
ErrorDocument 404 "404"    
RedirectMatch 404 ^/res/.*$
```

And I put everything that isn't **.htaccess** or **index.php** in /res/